# 2018 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discussion, election

In around 4 hours, [the nomination phase of the moderator elections](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) is scheduled to end. However, in order for the election to proceed, it is necessary to have at least one more candidate running than there are slots. This allows for there to be actual voting phases, so that the community can actually show that they support the candidates who are running. We will be extending the deadline for nominations for an additional seven days if the current deadline (20:00 UTC) approaches and there are insufficient candidates.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless someone wants to take on the responsibility. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: Ironically, hardly anybody will see this in time due to the severe delay with which changes of featured meta questions take effect …

Comment: Ideally it'll still prompt people to nominate during the period extension, though. Getting people to nominate in time for today (which is already too late technically, we already threw the extension switch) is not as important as getting people to nominate at all.

Comment: @GraceNote Can I just make a nomination and say "vote for WELZ"? or does the nomination have to be a serious one?

Comment: @ZachSaucier indeed whet i had been thinking

Comment: So what's going to happen if the election votes for someone that doesn't really want it?

Comment: @Zach Please do **not** do that. If the majority that nominate don't actually want the job, and only one person actually genuinely wants it, that doesn't say "We should pick that person", that says "Where is all the community that actually wants to take care of the site?"

Answer (score 7):

I considered giving it a shot considering I think I have a good background for this but the amount of time I can dedicate is limited by current life circumstances.

What are the community's/network's expectations with regards to time investment for moderators?

Comment: I think this would be a good topic for the [election chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77171/2018-graphic-design-moderator-election-chat).

Comment: @DarthVader Thanks, I wasn't sure about posting this here. I will take my question there :-)

Comment: The moderators of this site would give a better answer to time investment. How much time varies by site, workload, and moderator team size, so we don't have some sort of "standard" like "Try to check in for like an hour a day". The only standard we have is "This is a volunteer position, however much time you do put in shouldn't interfere with your life outside of the network".